# Flutter: Get information from scanned barcode number

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode

I am quite new to Flutter, and I am currently working on an application that needs barcode reading. So I used the [barcode_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) library, and I am now able to get the barcode number from a scanned barcode.

To be clear, **I am not asking how to scan a barcode / get the barcode number.**

My question is: how can I get more information about a product from its barcode number in Flutter (e.g. product name)? Can I do this from the `barcode_scan` library, or will I need something else?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, when scanning QR codes I am able to get the information it encodes (e.g. product name or URL), but this is not the case with barcodes.

My current (relevant) code is as follows:

```
String result = 'Hey there!';

Future scanBarcode() async {
    if(await Permissions.checkCameraPermission()) {
        try {
            await BarcodeScanner.scan().then((scan_result) {
            //here scan_result is the obtained barcode number
            setState(() { result = scan_result; });
        });

        }
        //handling exceptions...
    }
    else {
        setState(() { result = 'Camera permission denied'; });
    }
}
```

(Side note, here `Permissions.checkCameraPermission()` is a function I created to check if camera permission is granted, shouldn't be relevant for the question).

Comment: Use a UPC lookup? For example: https://www.barcodelookup.com/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the only plausible way to do it from Flutter would be to use a barcode lookup API like @RichardHeap proposed in the comments. If my app was Flutter only (without a backend server connected to it) I believe I would have gone that way.

But I guess I'll just send the barcode number itself to the backend and deal with it on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same plugin for scanning barcode or qr code for my flutter app..

```dart
String result = 'Hey there!';

Future scanBarcode() async {
    if(await Permissions.checkCameraPermission()) {
        try {
            // I get the scan result from BarcodeScanner this way and it is working for me.
            result = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
        }
        //handling exceptions...
    }
    else {
        setState(() { result = 'Camera permission denied'; });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this only gives you the barcode number, right? What I want is a way to get product information as well (e.g. product name).

Comment: @AnisR. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, on scanning the code, you need the information / data about the product.

If I understood it right, there are several aggregators of the barcode. You can get APIs from them. But there is not single place from where you get all the information.